# APIs for Nagios

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I want to know if there are any APIs available for creating users and project or user space in Nagios, so that we can automate the process using Python scripts.

Thanks & Regards,
Learner

Answer (score 0):

Nagios can´t do this for now, but fork of Nagios the Icinga2 have this feature. ([info](http://docs.icinga.org/icinga2/snapshot/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/icinga2-api))